# pass multiple values in BehaviourSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

How to pass multiple value to BehaviorSubject?

working fine with below single value

```
messageSource: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("");
```

***Error with multiple values***

```
messageSource: BehaviorSubject<[string,boolean]> = new BehaviorSubject<[string,boolean]>();
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` requires a default value to be passed:

```
messageSource: BehaviorSubject<[string,boolean]> =
       new BehaviorSubject<[string,boolean]>(['', false]);
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

when you want to update value you should also pass array:

```
this.messageSource.next(['foo', true])
```

Also, you can use object as a value instead.